# Styling the "directory listing" in Glassfish

Tags: css, web, glassfish, payara, directory-listing

I would like to consult about styling the "directory listing" in Glassfish server.

I am building a website using Glassfish server, a derivative of Payara Server. I enable the directory listing feature, but the appearance is not what I expect.
[image]

Is is possible to change the appearance, for example adding some CSS files? I have been Googling to find some solutions, but I could only find some settings for Apache server, e.g., [this](https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/).
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like you are using the Payara Server which is a derivative of Glassfish. No mention of that?

Comment: You are right, it is a derivative of Payara server. I modified the question and tag. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I tried to launch a server on my Desktop to solve this but if you have a live URL for me to check, please reply with that.

Comment: @m4n0, thanks a lot for your help. Unfortunately I do not have a live URL. It is a local server. I am now solving it by creating an `index.html` file for each directory. It is indeed very troublesome to create an `index.html` file for all directories, but I create a bash script to automatically generate it. So far so good.